# Trouble establishing proxy connection from React frontend to Express backend

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, axios

I am having trouble sending a JSON object using POST method from React frontend to Express Backend.
I get the following error when I submit the form:
**Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/create' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.**

Any help will be much appreciated. I do not want to enables CORS due to security implications, and setting proxy parameter in package.json of the React project is not working.

Here is some of my code:

```
const handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault(); 

   if(entry !== "" && dueDate > Date.now()){
       console.log({entryDate: entryDate, entry: entry, dueDate: dueDate});
    axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/create',
        data: {
          entryDate: entryDate,
          entry: entry,
          dueDate: dueDate
        }
      })
        .then(response => response.json)
        .then(data => {
            console.log(`Success:: ${data}`)
        })
        .catch(e => {
            console.log(`error: ${e}`)
        })
        toggle();
    
   } else {
       console.log("error")
   }


}
    <div>
        <Modal toggle={toggle} isOpen={modal} >
            <ModalHeader>Create Item</ModalHeader>
            <ModalBody>
                <Form>
                    <FormGroup>
                        <Label for="date">Date</Label>
                            <DatePicker id="entryDate" name="entryDate" onChange={onEntryDateChange} selected={entryDate}/>
                    </FormGroup>
                    <FormGroup>
                        <Label for="TODO">TODO</Label>
                        <Input type="textarea"
                            id="entry"
                            name="entry"
                            placeholder="Enter TODO here" 
                            onChange={onEntryChange}/>
                    </FormGroup>
                    <FormGroup>
                    <Label for="dueDate">Due date</Label>
                            <DatePicker id="dueDate" name="dueDate"onChange={onDueDateChange} selected={dueDate}/>
                    </FormGroup>
                </Form>
            </ModalBody>
            <ModalFooter>
                <Button color="success" block type="submit" onClick={handleSubmit}>Create <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faPlus} size="sm"/></Button>
            </ModalFooter>
        </Modal>
    </div>
)
```

}

// package.json - I have set the proxy to localhost:8080:
...

```
 "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:8080",'
```

...

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED**
I ended up using **axios.post** function with url string not including excluding localhost:8080. It seems like since its already specified proxy url in **package.json** file, I don't have to do it again when making a post call with axios.

Here's the updated code:

```js
axios
  .post('/create', data)
  .then((response) => response.json)
  .then((data) => {
    console.log(`Success:: ${data}`);
  })
  .catch((e) => {
    console.log(`error: ${e}`);
  });
```

Thanks anyways!